# How use java applet with javascript

Tags: java, javascript, asp.net-mvc, applet

what I do to use java to javascript:

step1:

I create in netBeans "Java Application":

```
package com.mkyong.applet;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.TextArea;

public class JavaScriptToJava extends Applet{

    TextArea textBox;

    public void init(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        textBox = new TextArea(5,40);
        add(textBox);
    }

    public void appendText(String text){
        textBox.append(text);
    }       
}
```

Builded.
Get copy file `...\build\classes\com\mkyong\applet\JavaScriptToJava.class` to `~/Content/applets/`

step2:

Create html view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.AppletABC.appendText('welcome to mkyong dot com');
    })
</script>

<h1>Javascript acess Applet method</h1>
<applet width=300 height=100 id="AppletABC" code="com.mkyong.applet.JavaScriptToJava.class" codebase="~/Content/applets/JavaScriptToJava.class">
</applet>
```

Load this page, I see the word "plugin is not".

What am I doing wrong? I need to call the java

UPDATE:

js errors:

> document.AppletABC.appendText('welcome to mkyong dot com'); not found
>   function appletABC

Comment: shouldn't the codebase refer to the applet's root directory?

Comment: I suggest wrapping the class file inside a jar as this might be neccessary if you have multiple classes.

Comment: Make your applet width and height larger, because right now you can't see all the words in the message. It might say "plugin is not installed" or "plugin is not supported" or something.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill, "no plug"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved to use the tag **archive**